# render html in a rich text box in active reports software

Tags: richtextbox, activereports

I have a string with basic html markup which I want to put into a rich textbox

```
 string ab  = @"<b> a b </b>"
```

I want it to render as it would appear in a browser ie:

**a b**

how can I do this in active reports 7? According to http://www.datadynamics.com/forums/77664/ShowPost.aspx, a richtextbox supports these tags. Do I have to specify a property to allow it to render html? How should I approach this?

Thanks,
Sam

More information (Update 8/11):

I'm binding the data from a database field - an oracle nclob. The field repeats within the detail section (with different information each time).

If I bind the field directly to a textbox or label it renders the string, but doesnt encode the html

```
 <b> a b </b>
```

but it encode the string.

---

Solution Summary

Solution (as suggested by @activescott)

- Bind rtx directly to the datafield
- 'Reformat' the text into html in
  the script

public void detail_Format()
{
   rtxBox.Html = rtxBox.Text;
}

result: renders the html field with some degree of html formatting

notes:

- binding directly in the script doesnt work,
  ie. rtxBox.Html = pt.Fields["CONT_ID"].ToString(); yields some wierd meta data string
- the Datafield only binding approach doesn't work
  (it will yield it as text)
- there are some extra spacing that occurs with p tags. It may be worth regexing them out or somehow providing some formatting control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual property you are looking for is [the Html Property](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.RichTextBox~Html.html). You can also load a file into that control using the [step-by-step walkthrough here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?LoadaFileintoaRichTextControl.html).

I am assuming you are using Section Reports and not Page Reports.

To use HTML from the database in a bound report, you should be able to use [the DataField property of the RichTextBox control](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.ARControl~DataField.html) (set it to the name of the corresponding Data field at design time). However, I noticed [this "Render HTML tags in DB in ActiveReport pdf or HTML" article](http://gurge.wordpress.com/2008/01/16/render-html-tags-in-db-in-activereport-pdf-or-html/)  which kind of implies that doesn't work since it loads the HTML from a database programatically. One of the two should work.

Comment: hmm, its not dead on I'm acually getting the data from a database field - an oracle nclob - that repeats for each detail (as opposed to from a file). I can render it as a string if I set it as a datafield for a label or textbox, but it doesnt encode the string

Comment: You need to use the **RichTextBox** control not a field/textbox or a label. I updated my answer.

Comment: okay, seems legit. I'll mark as answer once I confirm the approach works.

Comment: @user1778606 let me know if you have any questions or run into any issues.

Comment: So as a conclusion, I can't keep the styling I had in the HTML code (font name, size, color, underline ...)??